# How can I get a list of all open named pipes in linux?

Tags: linux, pipe

Is there a easy way to list all open named pipes on linux? O a bash command to show all open named pipes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option: you can use the **lsof** command line tool: https://www.simplehelp.net/2010/04/09/how-to-get-a-list-of-open-files-sockets-and-pipes-in-linux/